# Android 9Patch artifact in dropdown on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, nine-patch, android-6.0-marshmallow

I experience a problem with a via 9Patch-Image customized drop down on Android Marshmallow only which we use for the feedback activity.

It works on Android 2.3-5.1 and doesn't work on Android 6.0 anymore.

Okay, let's have a look at the code of the dropdown:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/mood_spinner"
    style="@style/Dropdown"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/feedback_type"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="42dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >
</Spinner>
```

uses style

```
<style name="Dropdown" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">65dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">11dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/dropdown</item>
</style>
```

which results in a dropdown style of (9Patch):

[image]

which is fine.

The dropdown has a custom ArrayAdapter and the items in the dropdown use the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/dropdown_inner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp" >

<ch.mobility.mobidroid.view.MobidroidTextView
    android:id="@+id/feedback_category_name"
    style="@style/Font"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout Background:

[image]

How it should look (Android 2.3 - 5.1) (Nexus 4):
[image]

How it looks on Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) (Nexus 5):
[image]

I have had a look at all the 9Patch images (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi) and couldn't find out what could be wrong with them. Does anyone of you have an idea?

Comment: `I have had a look at all the 9Patch images (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi)` Maybe, you didn't provide the required drawable, which has to be put in the **xxhdpi** bucket.

Comment: Can you further explain? I thought Nexus 5 is xhdpi? And shouldn't it then show the same behaviour on the Nexus 5 with Android 5.1 installed?

Comment: No, it's xxhdpi: http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_5-5705.php. 445 ppi fall into the 480 dpi bucket.

Comment: Oh, thank you for informing me about that. Is there some kind of tool to generate the xxhdpi 9Patch image? It's the first time I'm doing stuff like this as our Designer has left us in order to explore the world and I'm swimming a bit now. How do I handle this best?

Comment: Okay, now it works on Nexus 5, but not on Nexus 6 and some other xxxhdpi devices... How do I handle xhdpi --> xxhdpi --> xxxhdpi 9patch conversion? I don't know, I'm not a graphics designer and couldn't find any help on the net yet. These generators all screw up the 9patch :/

Comment: You should work on the "non-9 patched" image. Only after you have the scaled versions, add the 1 px border and the markers to each. Because the border **must not** be scaled (it has to be **exactly 1 px**). Nice tutorial: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Comment: There is no "non-9 patched" image. It's a color gradient done with a 9 patch image. The 9patch is the only thing I have available as resource :/. I as well  tried to replace the 9patch image with a xml drawable that defines the color gradient and that didn't quite work out as the color gradient didn't apply properly. Sorry to bug "you" about this and I'm very glad you're trying to help me out here!

Comment: Make your own "non-9 patched" image: just remove the 1 px border from all the sides.

Comment: Ok I'll try to go that way. Would this procedure work: 1. Take the xhdpi 9patch image 2. Remove 9patch relevant information (so I just have the color gradient) 3. Generate different density images 4. Turn the generated density images into 9patch images again by hand?

Comment: Yes, that's the way I'd do. (Just that I start from the highest resolution and scale **down**, for better results - not a big deal, in case of just a gradient).

Comment: The highest resolution I have available is xhdpi at the moment, so that's why I would start from there. Thank you for your help and I'll post my results in this question when I'm done. I just realize now how much I appreciated our Graphical Designer :)

Comment: OK, but (just to talk) a gradient is easily makeable in a graphic program. OR by using a GradientDrawable in Android and then adjusting that one in a graphic editor.

Comment: Yeah, our graphical designer probably made the gradient with Photoshop. I'll be using Gimp or Photoshop. I'll have a closer look at the GradientDrawable and decide and try which method works better for me. If I can make it work, for me, the xml solution is better understandable (I understand what I do then) than 9patches for now.

Comment: Simply save it as a bitmap, then edit the bitmap - Sorry, I was thinking "diagonally". Anyway, PhotoShop and Gimp will allow you to make any gradient at the desired resolution quite easily.

Comment: Hey @FrankN.Stein, thank you for your help. With the correct sized xxhdpi image it does indeed work now. But I have one more question, not sure if you can answer it: I created an xxxhdpi (correctly sized, 9patch) version for the nexus 6 and nexus 6p as well and that one doesn't work. Nexus 6 and Nexus 6p are between xxhdpi and xxxhdpi, so I guess it has to do with that and that scaling down doesn't work for 9patches. I ended up not providing an xxxhdpi version which turns out to be working for the nexus 6 and nexus 6p. Do you have an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Nexus 6 is 493 ppi and Nexus 6p is  518 ppi. They should both fall into the xxhdpi bucket (480 dpi)

Comment: That is not true: The Nexus 6 boasts an impressive 5.96” Quad HD screen display at a resolution of 2560 x 1440 (493 ppi). This translates to ~ 730 x 410 dp (density independent pixels). Nexus 6 has a quantized density of 560 dpi, which falls in between the xxhdpi and xxxhdpi primary density buckets.

Comment: There's no "between" (I sound like Yoda). It either falls into one or another normalized bucket.

Comment: Okay, weird because following confuses me now: I just noticed, that if I don't put the xxhdpi 9patch into the xxxhdpi folder, the rendering is broken on nexus 6 and nexus 6p. So it seems to pick up the xxhdpi 9patch from the xxxhdpi drawable folder. But if I put the xxxhdpi 9patch image into the xxxhdpi drawable folder the rendering is broken again. Seems like a pitfall. I assume, that for a device that falls into the xxxhdpi bucket rendering is wrong again because it's not really and xxxhdpi version. A lot to learn I have about images and 9patches in Android...

Comment: Ah btw. Nexus 6 and Nexus 6p are listed as xxxhdpi devices by google: https://design.google.com/devices/ I'm totally confused by the behaviour now :P

Comment: If a 9 patch looks "broken", then there is an issue in the 9 patch itself. Since 9 patches stretch in the specified areas, you should only see weird stretchings. Make sure you are using them as the background, not as a src. The markers black has to be pure black. And the 9 patch markers have to lie on a 1 px border (exactly 1 px).

Comment: It seems that Nexus 5X, 6 and 6P are a little "out of standard". Note the scale factor. It's not 2.0, 3.0, 3.0 respectively - as I would expect. Instead, it's 2.6, 3.5, 3.3, respectively. How weird.

Comment: I see weird stretchings I guess (same as above). I use it as a background on the drop down item RelativeLayout: android:background="@drawable/dropdown_inner". The markers are pure black from what I see with Photoshop and Sip. But not sure about the last point. Would you mind having a look at the below attached 9patches? I really think it has to do with the anormal scale factors of the Nexus 6, 6p and 5x

Comment: Last point, better explained (maybe): When you  add a transparent 1 px per side (2px horizontal and 2px vertical in total) to your canvas (the image is centered in the canvas) and then add the black markers.

Comment: Shouldn't draw9patch show me bad patches (not bad stretchings) if something is wrong with the 9patch itself? I just can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

xxhdpi 9patch:

[image]

xxxhdpi 9patch:

[image]

Comment: Now, these 9 patches tell me: There is one horizontal stretch. And it's all content area, in horizontal. There are 2 vertical stretches (the inside is kept from stretching). About 2/3rds are vertical content area, with 1/3rd not being occupied by (eventual) text.

Comment: That sounds how it correctly looks on the device (as seen in first post). So I assume you also don't see anything wrong that causes the black/gray stretching of the end of each column if I use the xxxhdpi version for xxxhdpi devices?

Comment: The black is real black. But I'm unsure of the transparency. I saw that the Image/Method is "Color Scale", instead of being "RGB Color". Maybe this can be an issue? The marker border has to be totally transparent (except the black markers).

Comment: I'll check the Color mode of the image in Photoshop again. I think beside of that everything should be ok. If this doesn't turn out to be the problem I really guess it has to do with these devices having "strange" scaling factors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96897/discussion-between-byemute-and-frank-n-stein).

Comment: I just checked with Photoshop. Color profile is sRGB. I changed it to Adobe RGB now and checked the transparency which looked good as well. Other than that it looks good but doesn't work. Ayy, this is somehow fishy

Comment: Yes, I must admit that it goes beyond my current science... :(

Comment: Same for me. I'll have to wait until the Samsung Galaxy S6 receives Android 6.0 as that device is exactly xxxhdpi (4x) and check then if it works with the xxhdpi image ind the xxxhdpi folder. Anyway, thank you for your patience, help and introduction to 9patches.

Comment: You don't have to wait. Just create an emulator... :) I do so. I don't buy all the devices. I test on mine, but I also test on emulated ones.

Comment: I don't trust the emulator as I don't trust the simulator for iOS :). Even though it's actually emulated for android and not just simulated as for iOS. But the Android Emulator takes up to 1 hour to start and is slow as hell (I can't use HAXM on my mac, why ever) and without HAXM it's a pain because I can just assign 2gb of ram...

Comment: FYI: I created an avd for the samsung galaxy s6 and ran the app on it. It seems to work for xxxhdpi screen with the xxhdpi 9patch in the xxxhdpi folder.

Comment: Which, again, seems very strange. Or, at least, illogical.